# How do I cut a hole through vinyl siding?

Tags: vinyl-siding

I would like to ventilate my bathroom fan to the exterior of my attic and outside. We have vinyl siding. What is the proper way to cut a hole in the siding?

I have a 4" hole saw for the wood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hole saw will do the job.  You don't need a perfectly clean cut here because your vent cover will hide the hole.

But - ideally - drill your pilot hole from inside, then drill thru from the outside with the hole saw.

Comment: So I don't have to pull it off, I can drill straight through with the siding still hung?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 4):

Cutting the vinyl siding is easy. A hole saw, tin snips, etc, will slice right through it. When we cut with a circular saw, we often install the blade backwards to minimize ripping and tearing of the vinyl. That said, the hole is the least of your effort. You need to be sure the weather stripping and siding itself is properly done to keep the siding water tight. See [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/15112/2196) for a full description of how to handle the tyvek, installing J-channel around the opening, and remove/reinstall the siding. One important consideration is that vinyl siding expands and contracts, so you don't want to make a fixed hole that fixes the siding to the house, otherwise you'll risk warping and buckling.